# How to bulk edit php function to replace certain keyword with custom list of keywords

Tags: php, notepad++, bulk

I have a function that adds new custom user roles. Now I need to add over 682 new user roles and I am doing it with the following function:

```
add_role(
'accountants-needed-western cape',
 __( 'accountants-needed-western cape' ),
 array(
    'read'         => true,  // true allows this capability
    'edit_posts'   => false,
 )
  );
```

Now how can I bulk generate that function but replace every instance of "accountants-needed-western cape" to my list of new user role name which is available here https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GGW171NY9S23. so i will need the above function over 682 times but with a unique user role name . (don't worry after the role is created I will be deleting the functions)

Is there a function i can run maybe on notepad ++ or any other freely available software? or how do you guys usually do this?

Comment: This? https://gist.github.com/ImSkully/cf194e8dd6292ab73d758aaa8f857ea8

Comment: Hi sorry my bad I could've been more exact in the question, I need ''accountants-needed-western cape',
 __( 'accountants-needed-western cape' ),' to be those values and by the way what software are you using to do this and thanks for the help @skully!

Comment: I am using Sublime Text 3, you can place multiple cursors using middle-mouse button to edit multiple lines at once, therefore being able to write the same thing across multiple lines at the same time. I still don't understand what you mean however of how it needs to look but I suggest you try Sublime Text and see if you can achieve it yourself.